# Property '_trigger' error - Pop up dialog in Jquery Mobile and MVC 3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, mobile, triggers, dialog

The following code inside a MVC 3 view generates an error **Error: Unable to get value of the property '_trigger': object is null or undefined** in IE9 when I click on the input button.
This is the view page:

```
@{    
     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".prePaidBtn").click(function (event) {
        $.mobile.changePage($('#ui-dialog-error'), 'pop', false, true);
    })
</script>
<input id="prepaidbtn1" class="prePaidBtn" type="button" value="1 cake" />
<div data-role="page" id="ui-dialog-error">
    <div data-role="header">
        test            
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">            
        test
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried changing the data-role to dialog but to no avail...
_Layout page is as follows:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en-GB">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>TestApp</title>
        <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>@ViewBag.HeaderString</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                @RenderBody()
            </div>
       </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

The debugger shows that c.data("page") is undefined... Google couldn't help this time around hence any ideas would be appreciated... Thank you...